# com/googlecode/flyway/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found

Tags: java, ant, build, flyway, ant-contrib

I am trying to do ant build. I have below configuration where build complains -

```
<taskdef uri="antlib:com.googlecode.flyway.ant" resource="com/googlecode/flyway/ant/antlib.xml" classpathref="flyway.lib.path"/>
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="./lib/ant-contrib-0.6.jar"/>
          </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

The build Completes with Success message and complains as below -

> [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource
>   com/googlecode/flyway/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Use the correct Antlib reference as documented: http://flywaydb.org/documentation/ant/